# Access query is asking for parameters for calculated field, how can I stop this?

Tags: ms-access, ms-query

I have a query set to calculate units processed per hour by user. The query returns the correct numbers when I run it, however every time that I run it , it will ask for parameters for two fields and I just click "ok".

When I link the query to a report, it will not display anything, but it does when I just open the query. What is going on ?

My query is set up as such .

- Column1 - Group By USERID
- Column2 - Sum of NBR OF UNITS: NBR OF UNITS
- Column3 - Sum of DURATION: DURATION
- Column4 - Expr1: [Sum Of NBR OF UNITS] / [Sum Of DURATION]

The Parameters asked for are

1. Sum Of NBR OF UNITS
2. Sum Of DURATION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column4 (if required) should be changed to:

```
Expr1: [NBR OF UNITS]/[DURATION]
```

Or, if a summation is required:

```
Expr1: Sum([NBR OF UNITS]/[DURATION])
```

You are prompted for the parameters because the aliases `Sum Of NBR OF UNITS` & `Sum Of DURATION` are not defined when the division expression is evaluated.